# parse the following string to year, month, date, hourOfDay, minute, second

Tags: java, string, parsing, date-parsing

How can i parse the following string `2000-05-12T12:00` to year, month, date, hourOfDay, minute, second?

I know to parse split it in "-" but there is efficient way to date for all the value?

I saw the solution like SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

but I need to update it to java calendar and i dont know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

Comment: @JamesBerners for future reference, you can [edit] your questions to include new information. Othere are less likely to see it in a comment (and you also aren't limited by comment formatting).

Comment: `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm", Locale.FRANCE).parse(s); Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(date);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use `SimpleDateFormat`. Have a look at the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Also you would have to look at the `Calendar` class. Java docs are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Try this -

```
String str = "2000-05-12T12:00"; 
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
Date d = parserSDF.parse(str);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);

System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)); // month in the Calendar class begins from 0
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Answer (score 0):

try use from `public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)` function.

read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) page and 
`(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String, java.text.ParsePosition)` for do it!